# Why am I not able to retrieve data - Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I recently added a column called user_cat to a table. I am not able to get this date to display on the webpage. However, I am able to display the data from columns user_id, email_id on the webpage using session variables using below.

```
$this->session->set_userdata("user_id", $this->session->userdata('loginUser') );

$this->session->set_userdata("user_id", $this->session->userdata('loginEmail') );
```

I checked the models page to and found the code to be like this.

```
$this->db->select('user_id,email_id');
```

&

```
'loginUser' => $row->user_id,

'loginEmail' => $row->email_id,
```

which i then changed to:

```
$this->db->select('user_id,email_id,user_cat');
```

&

```
'loginUser' => $row->user_id,
'loginCat'  => $row->   user_cat,
'loginEmail' => $row->email_id,
```

Now i used the session variable like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata("user_id", $this->session->userdata('loginCat') );
```

This did not work. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you didn't write the code yourself.Data from the database already set on the sessions. You can directly retrieve data using

```
this->session->userdata('loginUser')
```

So look for code like following in the model

```
$this->session->loginUser = //something;
//add your code
$this->session->loginCat = //similar to above
```

Take a look at [Database reference](https://devdocs.io/codeigniter~3/database/index).

However , following is the answer to your question

You are using same key to all session data. You should use a unique key for each session variable.

```
$this->session->set_userdata("user_id", $this->session->userdata('loginUser') );
$this->session->set_userdata("user_email", $this->session->userdata('loginEmail') );
$this->session->set_userdata("user_cat", $this->session->userdata('loginCat') );
```

Take a look at [Session library](https://devdocs.io/codeigniter~3/libraries/sessions).

Answer (score 0):

first set you session like this

```
$data = array(
                'loginUser' => $row -> user_id ,
                'loginEmail' => $row -> email_id,
                'loginCat' => "" ,
            );
$this -> session -> set_userdata ( $data );
```

then update it

```
$data = array('loginCat' => $row -> user_cat );
$this -> session -> set_userdata ( $data );
```